# Game Console Emulators (Nintendo, Super Nintendo, Sega Genesis, Nintendo 64, Gameboy...)

Tags: software-recommendation, games, emulation

What gaming console emulators are available in the latest 11.10 version.

If my english is wrong about gaming console emulator I am referring to Nintendo, Super Nintendo, Sega Genesis, Gameboy and others in that genre. What emulators are available to be able to play Rom games for this gaming consoles.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the repository there are emulators for lots of different game consoles.

- [DGen](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dgen) [image: Install scite] (Sega Genesis/MegaDrive).
- [FCE Ultra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fceu) [image: Install scite] (Nintendo 8-bit emulator).
- [FCEUX](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fceux) [image: Install scite] (Another Nintendo 8-bit emulator).
- [MAME](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mame) [image: Install scite] (Multiple Arcade Machine Emulator).
- [Mupen64plus](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mupen64plus) [image: Install scite] (Nintendo 64 emulator).
- [PCSX](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pcsx) [image: Install scite] (PlayStation emulator).
- [PCSX-Reloaded](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pcsx) [image: Install scite] (Another PlayStation emulator, fork of pscx).
- [ZSNES](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zsnes) [image: Install scite] (Super Nintendo emulator)
- [VisualBoyAdvance](http://packages.ubuntu.com/visualboyadvance) [image: Install scite] (Gameboy Advance emulator)
- [DeSmuME](http://packages.ubuntu.com/desmume) [image: Install scite] (Nintendo DS emulator)
- [gngb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gngb) [image: Install scite] (Game Boy Color emulator)
- [Yabause](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yabause) [image: Install scite] (Sega Saturn emulator)

There are also other emulators and compatibility layers for computers and systems, such as [Wine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wine) [image: Install scite], DOS, [Amiga](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uae) [image: Install scite], Atari, [Commodore](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vice) [image: Install scite].

Comment: Holycow! And I thought I was going to see about 6 or 7 of them. TOPS!

Comment: Is snes9x not available in Ubuntu?

Comment: snes9x is in previous versions, but absent in oneric:
You can get an older deb here or from debian. Unsure why it's no longer in the multiverse
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/s/snes9x/

Comment: yes, snes9x is in the repo.
I tried both the nes emus, and they both freeze when I try to configure the settings.
Are there any other nintendo emus?

Comment: Thanks balloons. I mention this since zsnes is basically abandoned for so long and snes9x is more up to date. I am saying this as a zsnes user that has not yet used snes9x but sees the updates come and come.

Comment: Just pointing out that VisualBoyAdvance also emulates GBC games.  Thanks for the great list!

Comment: Is there a GBA emu in Ubuntu that has a built-in cheat tool like the normal, Windows one?

Answer (score 3):

For users with 14.04+ this is an up to date list of the ones I have tested that also offer a GUI (Quick Save/Load, full compatibility and more), do not need to be compiled (Offer a DEB package) and have been tested up to and including 15.04:

**Sega Genesis** - [Gens/GS](http://segaretro.org/Gens/GS) (And also in Development [Gens/GS2](http://segaretro.org/Gens/GS_II) )

**Wii / Gamecube** - [Dolphin](https://dolphin-emu.org/)

**Nintendo 64** - mupen64plus Which is a package in Ubuntu

**PlayStation** - pcsxr which is a package in Ubuntu

**PlayStation 2** - pcsx2 which is a package in Ubuntu

**Nintendo DS** - desmume which is a package in Ubuntu

**Nintendo** - nestopia which is a package in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Try [Kega Fusion](http://www.eidolons-inn.net/tiki-index.php?page=Kega) it emulates sega megadrive, game gear, mega cd, master system and 32x.

Works great to.

Answer (score -1):

there is a great emulator on raspberry pi. it is called retro pie and you can get games from most of the systems here, except from the ds and ps2.
if you have a raspberry pi you just have to go on the web page and follow the steps provided and download the emulator station. Here you can download games from most platforms.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question actually being asked, in that what emulators are available for *Ubuntu*.