# Play my favorite games of PalyStation, Xbox,SEGA and Pc on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, games, repository, video-player, emulation

Lakka is a GNU / Linux distribution based on Retroarch and OpenELEC, with an interface with a look of mediacenter.

This distro has a wide catalog of emulators that will allow us to enjoy titles of the mythical consoles of SEGA, other Nintendo such as the NES, SNES and Gameboy, and even classics for DOS or some more modern games as the PlayStation or PSP.

What steps should I follow to work with Ubuntu in the same way that Lakka does?

My games will run just as well and in the same way as if I played on a game console?

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/   "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will likely be closed per the [FAQ.](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @ElderGeek I will consider what you say to me for future questions.

Comment: I think it would be fine if you asked about emulators for each console in a separate question here.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I consider your recommendations for future questions.

Comment: Game Console Emulators (Nintendo, Super Nintendo, Sega Genesis, Nintendo 64, Gameboy…)@ElderGeek This question is similar and none of you said anything about it, can I know why?

Comment: Game Console Emulators (Nintendo, Super Nintendo, Sega Genesis, Nintendo 64, Gameboy…) This question is similar and none of you said anything about it, can I know why?@Danatela

Comment: Game Console Emulators (Nintendo, Super Nintendo, Sega Genesis, Nintendo 64, Gameboy…) This question is similar and none of you said anything about it, can I know why? @rosch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Lakka OS is an emulator. They try to emulate games as if they were the original console. But all emulators are not the same and all have bugs and glitches that might or mightn't be on the console. Personally I have not used Lakka but I have used some emulators such as DOSBOX, PSX, PCSX2 and PPSSPP which emulate PS1, PS2 and PSP games and the DOSBOX can emulate not only games but applications and even windows (I have run Windows 3.11 and 95 but 98 is also possible). So long story short, maybe. The games might run better on Lakka . Well I'm not sure that this helps but I just wanted to say something.

[Edit]
 Well seeing what you added, you can make Ubuntu like Lakka by installing the emulators instead of having the OS just for emulating games. It is more complicated but hey it works and you have extra features not only emulating. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.You know emulators that work well in Ubuntu, you could improve the list of those that I put in the lines below?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they are not the best emulators for linux but this is what I have found and I share it with you.

#### PlayStation

1. PCSX2 (PLayStation 2)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install pcsx2-unstable
   ```
2. ePSXe/PCSX

   ```
   [Download Here](https://www.emuparadise.me/Sony_Playstation_Emulators/Linux/2)Here
   P.S: PCSX also available in Software Centre
   ```
3. PPSSPP

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppsspp/stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ppsspp
   ```

#### Nintendo

1. Mupen64 (N64 Emulator)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sven-eckelmann/ppa-mupen64plus
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install mupen64plus
   ```
2. ZSNES (Super Nintendo emulator)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install zsnes
   ```
3. Snes9x (Super Nintendo/SNES emulator)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bearoso/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install snes9x-gtk
   ```
4. Gngb (Nintendo Gameboy Color)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gngb
   ```
5. DeSmuME (Nintendo DS)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install desmume
   ```
6. VBA-M (Nintendo Game Boy Advance)

   [Download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vbam/files/VBA-M%20svn%20r1042/vbam-gtk_1.8.0.1042-1_i386.deb/download?use_mirror=ignum&r)
7. Dolphin (Gamecube / Wii / Triforce Emulator)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glennric/dolphin-emu
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install dolphin-emu
   ```

#### Windows

1. WINE

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
   ```
2. PlayOnLinux

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
3. DOSBOX

   ```
   [Download Here](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1)
   ```

Comment: Alberto, Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/872623/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**  (+1 as *now* it's a good answer!  **:P  ;-)**

Comment: DOSBox is just `sudo apt install dosbox`

Comment: Related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/87030/game-console-emulators-nintendo-super-nintendo-sega-genesis-nintendo-64-gam